# Flash SWF not playing!

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I created a custom video skin for my movie, and published the swf. The file plays on my Mac (using Flash player v9) but it will not play on my PC (using Flash player 10). When I uploaded it to the host, neither players will play the swf. The bitmaps in the flash file show up, but the movie won't play. I don't know if it is how I exported it or what, but it will not play! Any Idea why this is happening?

The video is hosted here: 
http://hqinternetsolutions.com/YOGIPATCH/index.html

Here is my Actionscript:
flvPlayback.playPauseButton = playpausebtn;
flvPlayback.muteButton = mutebtn;
flvPlayback.volumeBar = volbar;
flvPlayback.seekBar = seekbar;

And my HTML embedded flash:

```
<div id="movie">
    <object id="movie" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
    codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="440" height="273">
    <param name="movie" value="file.swf">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <embed src="file.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="440"
    height="273"></embed></object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a look using Firebug. Your swf appears to be referencing the following URL:

http://hqinternetsolutions.com/Users/larrykain/Desktop/flash%20skin/fullaquatic.flv

It's returning a 404 so it can't find the file. Looking at the URL, check the reference to how you've embedded it in the swf file.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by different things:

1. Make sure the flv file is uploaded to the server along with the SWF.
2. Your FLV file might be blocked on the web server. Make sure it's not by pointing your browser to the actual FLV file directly (example: http://hqinternetsolutions.com/YOGIPATCH/myvideo.flv)
3. The flv path set in the FLVPlayback component might be too long.
4. Try adding a preceding / to the path of FLV in the component.